# Android MediaRecorder to record a Surface (not Camera)

Tags: android, video, java-native-interface, mediarecorder

I'm looking at the class [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) of the Android SDK, and I was wondering if it can be used to record a video made from a Surface.
Example: I want to record what I display on my surface (a video game?) into a file. 
As I said in the title: I'm not looking to record anything from the camera.

I think it is possible by overriding most of the class, but I'd very much like some ideas...
Beside, I'm not sure how the Camera class is used in MediaRecorder, and what I should get from my Surface to replace it.

Thank you for your interest!

PS: I'm looking at the native code used my MediaRecorder to have some clue, maybe it will inspire someone else:
http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/media/jni/

Comment: Did you solved this issue? able to record a video from Surface? if yes, can you please give some idea about it...

Comment: the same question? did you solved this issues.

Comment: Hey I am trying to solve this issue. If solved I will let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible at the Java layer. All the communication between the Camera and Media Recorder happens in the native code layers, and there's no way to inject non-Camera data into that pipeline.

While Android 4.1 added the [Media Codec APIs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html), which allow access to the device's video encoders, there's no easy-to-use way to take the resulting encoded streams and save them as a standard video file. You'd have find a library to do that or write one yourself.

Comment: Alright, not possible at the java layer but I'm ok with using NDK. The thing is, I'm staring at mediarecorder source class since yesterday, and I still can't really figure out in which part it receives the camera frame. I think I'm missing something in its usage because every function seems almost empty (see link in the first post).

Answer (score 5):

The ability to record from a Surface was added in Android Lollipop. Here is the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#ScreenCapture

Answer (score 4):

Android 4.3 (API 18) adds some new features that do exactly what you want.  Specifically, the ability to provide data to `MediaCodec` from a Surface, and the ability to store the encoded video as a .mp4 file (through [MediaMuxer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html)).

Some sample code is available [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/), including a patch for a Breakout game that records the game as you play it.

Answer (score 1):

You MAY wish to trace the rabbit hole from a different folder in AOSP
frameworks/av/media
as long as comfortable with NDK (C/C++, JNI, ...) and Android (permissions, ...)

Goes quite deep and am not sure about how far you can go on a non-rooted device.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article on how to draw on a EGLSurface and generate a video using MediaCodec:

https://www.sisik.eu/blog/android/media/images-to-video

This uses OpenGL ES but you can have MediaCodec provide a surface that you can then obtain a canvas from to draw on. No need for OpenGL ES.